# main component not refreshing on statechange

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm having a few problems.

Basically, whenever the `switch` (Inside of EnableSwitch.jsx) is changed, it sets the state of the `saveBox` and then it should output console.log(2) (because the main App.js page should be rerendered because the state changed.  However, it doesn't do this. I'm unsure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-flower-28ogy9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In the `handleChange` function in `EnableSwitch.js`, you are calling `setSaveEnabled(true)` every time.  So that context value never change, thus no re-render. And you are using local state for the `Switch` component.  Instead, you should pass the context value `saveEnabled` to the `checked` prop, and update the `handleChange` function `setSaveEnabled(b => !b)` so that it toggles its state.

Comment: but it should change on the first button press since the state is set to `true` when its pressed the first time, which it doesn't. I was going to add the `toggle` functionality once I know it is working.

Comment: It changes because it is not a controlled component since you are setting the initial value to undefined instead of false: `const [checked, setChecked] = useState();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have just changed this, `checked` now has a default value of `false`. However, the main page component still does not re-render when the saveCOntext state is changed.

Comment: I mean you do not actually need to have a local `checked` state and sync it with the context vale. You can just use the context state directly. https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-forest-m7l8nu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FEnableSwitch.jsx

Comment: Thanks so much. I was stuck on this for sooo long! Much appreciated.